# Why does jQuery selector "$("*").not" not work?

Tags: jquery

I tried to write this function:

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
$("*").not(".one").css("color", "blue");
$(".one").css("background-color", "blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>

<p>g7z8h7u9jiokp</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p class="one">should have a black font color after button click</p>
<p>djkflöadjsdfklfösadj dfnasdkl</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p>jiorpojiweopk w</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
<span class="one">should have a black font color after button click</span>
<p>ijokp 4rwerw</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work. I want to except the blue font color for all elements with the `.one` class.

How is it possible to fix that?

Comment: If you want to modify all `<p>` elements then why do you select everything with `$("*")` instead of only the `<p>` elements (`$("p")`)?

Comment: Actually, it should work for all texts on my website, and not only for "p" ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you should never use `$("*")` as that includes all dom elements in the page including `html`, `head`, `style` and `script` tags, and changes all of them might create an undesired behaviour in the app. Also, if your page has lots n lots of elements, then transversing the full DOM might also take some time. You should best use a parent container and then you can use all children elements and its descendants like:

```
$("body *")
```

Demo:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("body *").not(".one").css("color", "blue");
  $(".one").css({"background-color":"blue", "color": "white"});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>

<p>g7z8h7u9jiokp</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p class="one">should have a black font color after button click</p>
<p>djkflöadjsdfklfösadj dfnasdkl</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p>jiorpojiweopk w</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
<span class="one">should have a black font color after button click</span>
<p>ijokp 4rwerw</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
```

Comment: Thank youuu, think that's the best solution!

Answer (score 3):

The code `$("*").not(".one").css("color", "blue");` won't change the font color of the `<p class="one">` tags, but it will change the font color of the parent tag, which will cascade down to all `<p class="one">` children, thus affecting them.

Try changing your code to `$("p").not(".one").css("color", "blue");`

Comment: Thank you! The thing is ... I'll have different tags and aaaall font colors on the website should be blue after the click, except the ones with the ".one" class.

Comment: Then use `$("body").css("color", "blue");` and add a CSS rule that keeps all `.one` tags the color you want, e.g. `<style>.one { color: black; }<style>`

Answer (score 0):

may be you could use this snipset.

```
$( "button" ).click(function() {
    $("*").css("color", "blue");
    $(".one").css("color","black");
});
```

```js
$( "button" ).click(function() {
 $("*").css("color", "blue");
  $(".one").css("color","black");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>

<p>g7z8h7u9jiokp</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p class="one">should have a black font color after button click</p>
<p>djkflöadjsdfklfösadj dfnasdkl</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p>jiorpojiweopk w</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
<span class="one">should have a black font color after button click</span>
<p>ijokp 4rwerw</p>
```

Comment: In this code you might as well use `$("*").css("color", "blue");`. kmoser already gave an explanation, `$("*:not('.one')")` will also select the parent of `.one`, so it will color blue. In that case, you remove the `:not` part, its unnecessary.

Comment: @LinkinTED thanks for the correction :), edited the answer.

Comment: Or.... instead of selecting all element, rather use `$("body").css("color", "blue");`. This however depends on the rest of the CSS. If an element gets a specific color defined further in the stylesheet, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Set background-color **and** font-color for your `.one` elements:

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $("*").not(".one").css("color", "blue");
  $(".one").css({
    "background-color": "blue",
    "color": "black"
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button>Button</button>

<p>g7z8h7u9jiokp</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p class="one">should have a black font color after button click</p>
<p>djkflöadjsdfklfösadj dfnasdkl</p>
<div>fdklfjöalsdkfdksla</div>
<p>jiorpojiweopk w</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
<span class="one">should have a black font color after button click</span>
<p>ijokp 4rwerw</p>
<span>ijokp 4rwerw</span>
```